# Not Receiving Email Relay from SendGrid to Rails 6 App using Action Mailbox & Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sendgrid, ruby-on-rails-6

Why is my Rails App in EC2 instance, through elastic beanstalk, not receiving the emails relayed by SendGrid?

Rails 6.0.2.2
Ruby 2.6.6

When running server in development using ngrok, the emails come in just fine.
When running the server in production `-e production` on my development server, the emails come in just fine.

However, when pushing the project live through Elastic Beanstalk, the emails do not come in.

The RAILS_INBOUND_EMAIL_PASSWORD key is saved as an environment variable through Elastic Beanstalk.

I have configured production.rb to use `config.action_mailbox.ingress = :sendgrid`

Here is what I have already tried:

- AWS Security: Opening all inbound ports from all sources to the EC2 instance for both the RDS database and EC2
- Changed `config.hosts.clear`, in production.rb
- changing the SendGrid relay to use the elastic beanstalk address, public IP address, and CNAME using both http and https
- Tried both `config.force_ssl = true` & false

I think this is an issue with some AWS setting, but I don't know what it could be.

Another fact I should mention is that getting to this point has been a nightmare and I wonder if something I did along the way messed it up.

I had to change `local: service: S3` inside storage.yml cause Action Mailbox kept looking for the email on the disk even though it clearly uploaded to S3 and the setting for Active Storage is set this way. `config.active_storage.service = :s3`

The above being on my development server.

I don't know what code you would need to see so let me know and I'll paste it in here.

Any help or direction would be wonderful!

Thanks.

**---UPDATE 6.25.20---**

I have abandoned using SendGrid and switched to using Mailgun.
The issue persists.

The mail is relayed just fine through ngrok.
When using the production environment on own server, the mail comes in just fine and is processed.
However when on production using elastic beanstalk with identical settings, the mail doesn't show up. The logs don't show that anything was received.

What setting could it possibly be in AWS? I've disabled all security I know of, opened all ports.
All curl requests come through just fine.
What computer gods have I upset?

Comment: Do you have the application running in production? Can you connect to it manually over SMTP?

Comment: It is running on production. I don't know what you mean by connecting directly over SMTP. do you mean connect to it over SSH? Yes, I can connect over SSH.
I am using SMTP with an exchange server to send out emails.

Comment: Sendgrid ingress then, when you submit an email through it (by hand) does the application see and process the email?

Comment: In development, when using the built in conductor or using ngrok, the emails come in just fine and are processed as expected. When hosting on aws, I don't see anything in the logs that say the email was received, bounced, or rejected. It's as if no email was ever sent.

Comment: What does your application tell you when you submit an email in production?

Comment: The endpoint described here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html#sendgrid

Comment: Correct. So I am forwarding emails form my gmail account to an email address that is linked to SendGrid, that then relays it to endpoint `https://actionmailbox:PASSWORD@example.com/rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails`
where the password is my `RAILS_INBOUND_EMAIL_PASSWORD` stored as a environment variable and the domain is actually a subdomain of our current production server. (for testing)

Comment: Submit email manually to that endpoint in your application instead of using third party services.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are requesting. 
The server I have uses Action Mailbox to read incoming mail to pull data from the email and put it into our database. It doesn't send out or reply to those emails.
This server isn't an SMTP server, it's only used to receive mail using Action Mailbox.

Comment: Use curl to talk to your application in production and verify it works as expected. Do not use gmail, sendgrid, aws anything, etc. Research how the sendgrid ingress works if you don't know and speak it to your application using curl.

Comment: So I sent a few emails using curl and the logs on the production server show that they were received. I don't know much about using curl, so I'll play around with this a bit more.
The issue seems to be SendGrid not relaying the message or AWS blocking it.

Comment: Train sendgrid at your development ngrok instance to find out which it is.

Comment: SendGrid sends the emails to the ngrok just fine using the same method and credentials. What on AWS could be blocking this POST request? I already opened all ports and disabled any relevant security methods I could find.

Comment: My curl request is using the same https request as on SendGrid and the EC2 instance is accepting that request meaning that AWS is NOT blocking outside POST requests.
Meaning that the issue is with SendGrid, right? But then why does it work when directing email to my dev server?

Comment: That I don't know but I would investigate what logging sendgrid provides.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Were you able to see the emails coming through via the EB logs?